# AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

In earlier versions of ASP.NET we usally used a property named [AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.antiforgeryconfig.uniqueclaimtypeidentifier(v=vs.111).aspx) for claims-based authorization to set the claim type from the identity that was used to uniquely identify the user.

How is this done in ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score -3):

As near as I can tell what you are looking for is to set up a `SignInManager` in the `Startup.cs` class's `ConfigureServices` method like so:

```
services.AddScoped<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>, AvantiaSignInManager<ApplicationUser>>();
```

Then you can implement your own `SignInManager` like the following:

```
public class AvantiaSignInManager<TUser> : SignInManager<TUser> where TUser : class
```

You will have to implement the `CreateUserPrincipalAsync` method like the following:

```
public override async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateUserPrincipalAsync(TUser user) {
  var Principal = await base.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);
  var Identity = (ClaimsIdentity)Principal.Identity;

  // How To: Here is where you can add Custom/On the fly Claims
  // They would not be persisted in the database but are within the Cookie

  var Employee = _dataContext.Employees
    .Include(x => x.Tenant)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.Subscriber)
    .Where(x => x.Email == Identity.Name)
    .SingleOrDefault();

  // See if there are any Claims linked to this user
  var MyClaims = _dataContext.EmployeeRoleClaims
    .Where(x => x.EmployeeID == Employee.ID)
    .Select(x => x.RoleClaim)
    .ToList();

  if (Employee != null) {
    // Add common Claims for every user, but the values are unique to them
    Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(Constants.Claims.Employee.ID, Employee.ID.ToString()));
    Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(Constants.Claims.Employee.Number, Employee.Number));
    Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(Constants.Claims.Tenant.ID, Employee.TenantID.ToString()));
    Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(Constants.Claims.Tenant.Name, Employee?.Tenant.Name));
    Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(Constants.Claims.Subscriber.ID, Employee?.Tenant.SubscriberID.ToString()));
    Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(Constants.Claims.Subscriber.Name, Employee?.Tenant?.Subscriber.Name));

    // Add any special Claims - May not be necessary within your application
    foreach (var rc in MyClaims) {
      Identity.AddClaim(rc.ToClaim()); // Add the Claim normally

      if ((rc.ClaimType == Constants.Claims.Subscriber.Administrator) ||
        (rc.ClaimType == Constants.Claims.Subscriber.TimeSheetAdmin) ||
        (rc.ClaimType == Constants.Claims.Subscriber.TimeSheetReview)) {
        var myTenants = _dataContext.Tenants.Where(x => x.SubscriberID == Convert.ToInt64(rc.ClaimValue)).ToList();

        foreach (var t in myTenants) {
          if (rc.ClaimType == Constants.Claims.Subscriber.Administrator)
            Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(Constants.Claims.Tenant.Administrator, t.ID.ToString()));
          else if (rc.ClaimType == Constants.Claims.Subscriber.TimeSheetAdmin)
            Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(Constants.Claims.Tenant.TimeSheetAdmin, t.ID.ToString()));
          else if (rc.ClaimType == Constants.Claims.Subscriber.TimeSheetReview)
            Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(Constants.Claims.Tenant.TimeSheetReview, t.ID.ToString()));
        } // foreach of the Tenants within the Subscription
      } // if I am the Administrator of a Subscription, I should also get the Tenants as well
    } // foreach of the Claims that have been specifically assinged to me

    // Add Claims for each of the Projects I am a Manager of or a Member of
    var PM = _dataContext.ProjectRoles.Where(x => x.Name == "Project Manager").FirstOrDefault();

    if (PM != null) {
      // Get the Projects where I am the Project Manager
      var MyPMProjects = _dataContext.ProjectProjectRoleEmployees.Where(x => x.EmployeeID == Employee.ID && x.ProjectRoleID == PM.ID).ToList();

      foreach(var Project in MyPMProjects)
        Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(Constants.Claims.Project.ManagerOf, Project.ProjectID.ToString()));

      // Get the Projects that I am ON but am NOT the Project Manager
      var MyProjects = _dataContext.ProjectProjectRoleEmployees.Where(x => x.EmployeeID == Employee.ID && x.ProjectRoleID != PM.ID).ToList();

      foreach (var Project in MyProjects)
        Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(Constants.Claims.Project.MemberOf, Project.ProjectID.ToString()));
    } // if we found the Project Manager Role
  } // if we found the associated Employee record

  return Principal;
}
```

I then created a `BaseController` that overrides the default `Controller` class as such:

```
public class BaseController : Controller {

  internal ILogger logger;

  public string UsersLoginName => User.Identity.Name;
  public long UsersEmployeeID => User.HasClaim(x => x.Type == Constants.Claims.Employee.ID) ? Convert.ToInt64(User.FindFirst(Constants.Claims.Employee.ID).Value) : 0;
  public long UsersTenantID => User.HasClaim(x => x.Type == Constants.Claims.Tenant.ID) ? Convert.ToInt64(User.FindFirst(Constants.Claims.Tenant.ID).Value) : 0;
  public long UsersSubscriberID => User.HasClaim(x => x.Type == Constants.Claims.Subscriber.ID) ? Convert.ToInt64(User.FindFirst(Constants.Claims.Subscriber.ID).Value) : 0;

}
```

This would allow me to, from any xxxController inheriting from my `BaseController` to do things like:

```
model.EmployeeID = UsersEmployeeID;
```

I realize it has been months since you asked this question, but for you and anyone coming to this after the fact, hope it helps out.

Comment: I don't understand how your answer relates to antiforgery token support?

Comment: My apologies.  I thought you were really just wanting to some how verify the unique user.